# Doughnut chart: faster way to detect which slice contains a point

Tags: c, charts

I have a doughnut chart, and I'd like to know which slice contains the blue dot (detecting a click on it):

[image]

The library I'm using is not able to do this (was not able to do doughnut out-of-the-box either, so I've implemented that).

I'd prefer some cool idea if exists. These parameters are easily available:

- center of the chart (which is also the center of the ring)
- radius of both outer and inner circle
- data

These parameters are *not* or *not easily* available:

- coordinates of the slices

I know this can be done with some easy `sin` and `cos` functions, but still, is there any "wiser" way?

Comment: What's wrong with sin and cos? Using them sounds pretty "wise" to me.

Comment: If the coordinates of the slices are not available, what is available ? The corresponding angles ? The relative weight of each slice? Note that the angle of a point `x, y` is easy to calculate with `atan2(y, x)`.

Comment: "data" = all data, so I can SUM them and get the relative weight, yes.

Comment: the problem is that I actually *have* the coordinates in the plot function which is very deep in the plot library. So I'd prefer to: 1.) not to calculate those points again, and 2.) wiser way = IF exists a way without knowing the exact coordinates

Comment: If you know the weight of each slice, you can calculate opening and final angles of each slice, and then use the angle of the point.

Comment: `atan2`!! That was I was looking for.

Comment: [illustration of `atan2`](https://www.mathopenref.com/arctan.html)

Comment: Pick one language to ask about, C or C++, and remove the tag for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the coordinates *x* (horizontal, positive to the right) and *y* (vertical, positive up) of the dot:

- Subtract the coordinates of the center of the circle. (For simplicity, I will reuse the labels *x* and *y* for the new coordinates after subtraction.)
- If *x*<sup>2</sup>+*y*<sup>2</sup> is less than the square of the inner radius or greater than the square of the outer radius, then the dot is not in the band. (Note that rounding issues in floating-point arithmetic can cause this determination to be off very slightly. If you care about high precision, further work is necessary.)
- Otherwise, `atan2(x, y)` gives the angle (in radians) clockwise from the top of the circle to the dot. (Note `atan2` is often written with arguments `atan2(y, x)`, but that gives the angle counterclockwise from the horizontal x axis. I swapped them for the desired orientation.)
- Dividing by 2π (`2*M_PI`, defined in `<math.h>`) gives the angle as a fraction of the circle (0 to 1), but it will be negative if the dot is on the left. If it is negative, add 1.

This angle can then be compared to the data to ascertain which slice it is in. (Take care for what you want to do if the angle happens to be exactly on a slice border, including if the angle is exactly 0 or 1.)